# How to setImage of a UIButton and subsequently remove it (animation)

Tags: objective-c, animation

I'm trying to set the image of a UIButton to some image for a set amount of time, and then after that time, I want the button to remove the image.  Here is the code I have been using and it isn't seaming to work.  If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}completion:^(BOOL finisheds){
    [button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a method in your class, something like this:

```
- (void)removeImageFromButton:(id)button {
     [button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal]
}
```

Then you can do what you want to do like this:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"light.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self performSelector:@selector(removeImageFromButton:) withObject:button afterDelay:5.0];
```

Also, you probably want to add `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformSelectorRequestsWithTarget:self];` in `- (void)dealloc` or else you make get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if `self` is deallocated before the 5s is up.